# No puedo marcar como leída una notificación

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de marcar como leída una notificación. Al intentar ir a la ruta pasandole el id de la notificación me da el error 404, sin embargo si pongo manualmente un id mas simple y corto si funciona.

Me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::post('/notifificaciones/leida/{id}', 'NotificationsController@read')->name('notifications.read');
```

Este es mi metodo:

```
public function read($id){

    DatabaseNotification::find($id)->markAsRead();

    return back();
}
```

Esta es la petición por ajax:

```
 methods: {
        markAsRead(notification){
            axios.post('/notificaciones/leida/' + notification.id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: estás utilizando Ajax para hacer el envío del ID?

Comment: @JoséVásquez si, tambien estuve utilizando un formulario y me daba el mismo error.

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo donde estas enviado la petición al controlador?

Comment: @BPolanco por favor agrega como esta constituido tu ajax

Comment: @BetaM acabo de ponerlo.

Comment: y cuál sería un ejemplo de ID más simple?

Comment: @ffflabs en vez de pasarle el uuid que es una combinación de letras y números, le paso un simple número.

Comment: Pero esa tabla qué llave primaria tiene? Es autoincremental o uuid

Comment: Tiene uuid que es el que genera Laravel cuando crea la notificación.